# Saving runBaseBatch class created file in distant directory

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

I wrote a job that generates pdf files with salesQuotation report, the files are created in a network directory . This job works fine.

Then, I wrote a class that do the same as the job but in a runBaseBatch class.

It doesn't work and I have the following error message in batch job form registry button:

> The use of printer is prohibited on this server

If the server is the AOS, I have working printers on it, the created files are written on another Server that has working printers

I used reportRun class and printJobSettings() method, it works in job not in batch job.

Edit: thanks for answers, my config is now ok but I have the following problem: my runbasebatch class works only if the checkbox batch is not checked in the configuration runbaseBatch dialog, i can't schedule my batch, if I check batch, I have no error but my files are not generated.
any ideas?

Comment: Not generated, most likely security related. Try to debug: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/x/archive/2009/06/25/step-by-step-checklist-for-debugging-batch-jobs-in-dynamics-ax.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the "Allow clients to connect to printers on this server" checkbox in Server configuration utility has been ticked, and AOS restarted.

I read somewhere that due to some bug the correcponding value in the registry should be tweaked, but I'd suggest checking if ticking the checkbox works first.

Answer (score 1):

Read on how to [Enable printing from a computer running Application Object Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa569633%28v=ax.50%29.aspx).

Complement with this blog entry in [AX Q&A](http://ax2009.wordpress.com/2010/04/13/print-report-from-batch-jobs/).